Missing extension byte exception using patrol test in flutter app
I have a Widget (Main Widget of the app) which renders normal when I install it as flutter app, yet during patrol test it throws an error concerning UTF-8 extension bytes.
FormatException: Missing extension byte (at offset 1066)
#0      _Utf8Decoder.convertChunked (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1956:7)
#1      _Utf8ConversionSink.addSlice (dart:convert/string_conversion.dart:304:28)
#2      _Utf8ConversionSink.add (dart:convert/string_conversion.dart:300:5)
#3      _ConverterStreamEventSink.add (dart:convert/chunked_conversion.dart:69:18)
#4      _SinkTransformerStreamSubscription._handleData (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart:111:24)
#5      _RootZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1594:10)
#6      _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:365:11)
#7      _BufferingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:297:7)
#8      _SyncStreamControllerDispatch._sendData (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:784:19)
#9      _StreamController._add (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:658:7)
#10     _StreamController.add (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:606:5)
#11     _Socket._onData (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:2455:41)
#12     _RootZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1594:10)
#13     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:365:11)
#14     _BufferingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:297:7)
#15     _SyncStreamControllerDispatch._sendData (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:784:19)
#16     _StreamController._add (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:658:7)
#17     _StreamController.add (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:606:5)
#18     new _RawSocket.<anonymous closure> (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:1942:33)
#19     _NativeSocket.issueReadEvent.issue (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:1385:14)
#20     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:40:21)
#21     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:49:5)
#22     _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:118:13)
#23     _RawReceivePort._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:185:5)

I tried to clean the pub cache, clean the app, etc.
I also tried to comment out all characters that might need an extension byte.
Nothing seems to help.
The patrol standard test from the first steps readme works though.
The test which is not working:
 patrolTest(
'Login',
($) async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  HydratedBloc.storage = await HydratedStorage.build(
    storageDirectory: await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory(),
  );
  // Replace later with your app's main widget
  await $.pumpWidgetAndSettle(StoreApp());
  await $.waitUntilExists($(TextField));

  expect($(TextField), findsAny);
},

);
What am I doing wrong here?
For clarification, I am initialising HydratedBloc.storage here, because in the real app it is done within the main method and without it I got a different error.
